# JSLint error: "Expected a newline at EOF", conflict with Beautify plugin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jslint

I have a problem while building the sources using Grunt, with JSLint task for error check:

> L177: Expected a newline at the end of the file. 
>   Warning: Formatting check failed. Use --force to continue. 
>   Aborted due to warnings.

The problem is obvious, but I use also the Beautify plugin for Brackets from: https://github.com/drewhamlett/brackets-beautify which by default removes all the new lines from the end of file.

My configuration for JSLint task in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
jslint: {
            server: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.PATH %>/src/**/*.js',
                ],
                directives: {
                    indent: 4,
                    plusplus: true,
                    unparam: true,
                    todo: true,
                    globals: [
                        'angular'
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    edition: 'latest', // specify an edition of jslint or use 'dir/mycustom-jslint.js' for own path
                    errorsOnly: true, // only display errors
                    failOnError: true // defaults to true
                }
            }
        }
```

My question is, how to change the JSLint configuration in Gruntfile.js to ignore the newline at EOF or to force the Beautify plugin to add (or simply do not remove) the new lines at the end of file?

Comment: why does it matter to you if there's a newline or not?

Comment: @dandavis Because he gets an error otherwise?

Comment: lint provides advice to coders. if you know what it's talking about, it's safe to ignore the advice. coding to pass every little lint in an automated workflow is not really the intended use... that said, try relaxing the messy whitespace options.

Comment: @dandavis I think you didn't understand the situation. OP is trying to build a project that uses grunt. One of the tasks is linting the files with JSLint. OP knows that those are only hints, but the build still aborts because JSLint is a hardliner. OP now wants to know how he can prevent JSLint from aborting the build because of missing newlines, without disabling JSLint entirely.

Comment: @Siguza Thank you for the clarification to others. This is exactly what I'm looking for as an answer to my question.

Comment: i know the situation, i just don't think the effort to fix a non-problem will be worth it if the lint messy option doesn't handle it and you're looking at an extra custom task to add a line break or forking lint/Beautify...

Comment: @dandavis Unfortunately, it's production code, not my own development. Other team members do not use Beautify and set up this JSLint constraints in Gruntfile. I have to adjust in some way. But of course if this task will require too much effort, I will disable Beautify plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Brackets Beautify Documentation](https://github.com/drewhamlett/brackets-beautify), it uses [JS-Beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) internally. The documentation for the latter mentions these parameters:

```
-n, --end-with-newline
-p, --preserve-newlines
```

If you can force Adobe Brackets to pass parameters to the js-beautify call, I guess one of these should do the trick.

*UPDATE*

According to the Github repo, brackets beautify uses a `settings.json` internally for configuration. Adding

```
"end_with_newline": true
```

might be easier than hacking the command-line call.

*2nd UPDATE*

If I understand the [README](https://github.com/drewhamlett/brackets-beautify/blob/master/README.md) correctly, an extension is just a folder, so this should work:

- find the extensions folder: menu "Help > Show Extensions Folder"
- locate the subfolder for the Beautify plugin
- change settings.json inside the plugin folder
- (probably) restart Adobe Brackets

Comment: I like your updated answer, but could you provide more information how to change settings.json file? Where can I find it and add this line?

Comment: See my updated answer (I don't use Adobe Brackets, so take this information with a grain of salt)

Comment: Excellent, it works as expected. Brackets restart was required. I accept your answer. Thank you.